# Remi: Which repository contains what?

Tags: repository, centos8, dnf

If I add the remi repository with `dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm` I get 3 files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` that declare following repositories:

```
remi-modular
remi-modular-test
remi
remi-test
remi-debuginfo
remi-test-debuginfo
remi-safe
remi-safe-debuginfo
```

I'm missing some few introductorily  words about how the packages are organized and when to use what. When should I use the remi, the remi-safe or the remi-modular repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule you should enable `remi-safe`, `remi` and `remi-modular` (but all three of these should already be enabled). These repos together contain the packages and module streams you expected to install from remi.

These repos break down as follows:

- remi-safe contains packages which are required by other packages in the main repos remi and remi-modular, but are not included with the Linux distribution you are using. It is called "safe" because it does not replace any packages shipped by the distro.
- remi and remi-modular contain the packages you are interested in. These may replace and override packages and module streams included by your distribution. Module streams are included in the remi-modular repo, and other packages are in the remi repo.

The remi-test and remi-modular-test contain updates which are being tested before general release in the remi and remi-modular repos. You generally won't enable these, but if you are having a problem with a package, you might get early access to an update through these repos.

The debuginfo repos contain debuginfo RPMs which are used when debugging a program or through automatic bug reporting. You also won't enable these repos; ABRT will automatically install packages from them if needed for bug reporting, and you would manually install them (e.g. to run the debugger yourself) with `dnf debuginfo-install <package>`.

Comment: Additional notice: only "remi-safe" is enabled by default as it is safe.  "remi-modular" is enabled but available streams need to be enabled explicitly.

Comment: And as usually, see the Wizard: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: Oh I think you're right. They're enabled on my systems because my Ansible playbook enables them.

Comment: `remi` doesn't seem to be automatically enabled. What could be the reason?

Comment: @robsch You did not read his statement directly above?

Comment: Ok, you're right. Didn't read it... Another question to @RemiCollet: For multiple versions the wizard tells to use Software Collections. Is this still the recommended way? I have installed multiple versions via Module Streams and all seems to work.

Comment: No, only SCL allow multiple version, Module streams only allow a single version (excepted if you are running in container)

Comment: @RemiCollet Yes, sorry. I'm still learning. Actually, I installed it that way: `dnf install php73 php74 php73-php-fpm php74-php-fpm...`. Now I can use both versions on command line and with apache. Is this already a Software Collection? Or what would the result if a SC is used?

Comment: yes, this is SCL.
Read https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl

Comment: BTW, this is probably not the better place for questions, please prefer the dedicated forum  https://forum.remirepo.net/